# Looking for a more efficient way to remove d3 elements

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, d3.js, svg

I just started learning D3 and am having trouble understanding how to manipulate selections. My visualization is functioning very slowly and someone recommended to me to use Timeline to find the source of the problem. I looked over it and found that this snippet of code is most likely the culprit:

```
for (var i = 0; i < staticSvgLength; i++) {
    var curritem = d3.select(svgChildren[0][i]);
    if (curritem.attr("class") != "graphbutton") {
        curritem.remove();
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the timeline that suggests to me that the problem is remove:
[image: Timeline]

`svgChildren` elements are selected using:

```
var svgChildren = d3.selectAll(svgContainer[0][0].childNodes);
```

There are thousands of elements, most of which can be found within the following variable:

```
var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("svg")
    .data(rawDataStore)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
```

This is the graph I am trying to create:

[image]

The elements which I'm trying to prevent from being removed are the buttons in the upper left corner which are also stored in `svgContainer`. As a side question, is it bad practice to store the buttons in the same `svg` element I store the main graph?

EDIT: Here is where I define `svgContainer`:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("Call", "svgContainer")
    .attr("height", max_y)
    .attr("width", max_x)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top) + ")");
```

I select all the `SVG`s to be removed because when you click a button, it switches to a different graph. I don't want the two buttons to be removed, only the graphs, so I tried to exclude them from the selection by giving them a class and then removing all elements in `svgContainer` excluding the items that have the button class.

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow... but we need more code: what is `svgContainer`? Why are you selecting all SVGs? What are you removing, just rects? By class?

Comment: I added an edit containing more information. Hope it makes it more understandable!

Comment: you should look at how selections work. data update, enter and exit
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Comment: How many SVGs do you have in this visualisation?

Comment: Anyway, without seeing the code, this is the best I can do: change your rectangles: `var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect").data(rawDataStore).enter().append("rect")`. Then, for whatever element you want to remove, give them a class: `.attr("class", "someClass");` and drop that for loop, remove all them by: `d3.selectAll(".someClass").remove()`. Just a last word: normally, beginners use `remove()` to update the data, and I believe that's your case (because of the buttons). If that's the case, change your approach.

Comment: When your using `for` loops in D3 it usually means that you are doing it wrong. Try Gerardo's suggestion, `d3.selectAll(".graphbutton").remove()`

Comment: Why not just put all those `children` inside one `<g>` element and keep the buttons outside? You won't even need a new selection for removal, just keep a reference `var g` to the group and remove it and all its children without a hassle by calling `g.remove()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! @GerardoFurtado I am going to take your advice and refactor the code such that I do not remove elements every time I update the data.